# Highlight duplicate values between two or more ranges

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

I have a range of cells that I want to highlight duplicates in the same column. 
using `=match(C$21,C$7:C$10,0)` applied to the range `C7:H10`.

**Expected outcome:**

1. If there is a duplicate in the range it highlights the whole range of that column ie `C7:C10`, I would like it to highlight only the duplicated cell. ie C7.
2. I need it to look for conflicts between the range `C7:C10` and `C21:C24`. on my test sheet shared below I have colored the rows that should not duplicate with light purple, or light magenta (two seperate conflict groups). Columns C, D, E have the conditional formatting. Columns G, H are static formatted the way I would like it to show.

Any help appreciated.

[Highlight Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DlPqLMRggf2atMz6UwlGeohNKvw8C5-tFaD2UfteBVU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

orange group:

```
=REGEXMATCH(C7, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $C$21:$H$24))
```

blue group:

```
=REGEXMATCH(C11, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $C$23:$H$25))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tuuq4VZg1aouS66AsuamzmFa7xyY0adoHenvaiGJ-qY/edit#gid=0)